# How to store an empty array in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, oracle

I am running into an issue with PHP/SQL

I tried to pass an empty array to SQL with `oci_bind_array_by_name` and

```
oci_bind_array_by_name($stid, ":c1", $array, 5, -1, SQLT_CHR);
```

will give me `'Maximum array length must be greater than zero'` error

However, if I first detect the array length and skip `obi_bind_array_by_name` if array is empty, I will get error from SQL

```
'not all variables bound'
```

I need to store empty array sometimes to sql. I am not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to bind all your variable, even if they don't have a value so for

```
select * 
from t1 
where t1.id = :1
```

You'd still have to set :1 to a value and if you want to ignore that condition do:

```
select * 
from t1 
where (t1.id = '' or '' is '');
```

assuming it was set to an empty string.